# calculating sum of csv file in Python 3.6.2

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.6.2 and have a csv file that looks like this:

```
STATE,RATE,DEATHS
IA,4.2,166
NH,4.2,52
MA,4.3,309
CA,4.4,"2,169"
CO,4.6,309
ID,4.6,106
NY,4.6,"1,087"
VT,4.6,27
NJ,4.7,487
WA,4.9,432
```

I am trying to calculate the sum of the "RATE" column. However, with my current code below I keep getting the error: "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". I am fairly new to Python and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import csv
with open('infant_mortality.csv', 'r') as f:
  next(f) #skips the first row
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    total = sum(float(row[1]))
  print('The total is {}'.format(total))
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're usin `sum()` which requires an iterable like a list, simply add a starting value to total and then sum all values to total with `total += value`

```
import csv
with open('infant_mortality.csv', 'r') as f:
  next(f) #skips the first row
  total = 0
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    total += float(row[1])
  print('The total is {}'.format(total))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('infant_mortality.csv')

print('The total is {}'.format(df['RATE'].sum()))
```

Answer (score 0):

sum() expect a iterable object, but when you write ***sum(float(row[1]))***,  row[1] is a single value, not iterable like a list (the 'row' list in your case)

From python docs

> sum(iterable[, start])
>
> Sums start and the items of an iterable from
> left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. The
> iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not
> allowed to be a string.

Example of use sum()

```
list_number = [2,3,5]
print sum(list_number)
10
```

Maybe the code bellow can help you.

```
import csv
total = 0
with open('infant_mortality.csv', 'r') as f:
  next(f) #skips the first row
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    total += float(row[1])
  print('The total is {}'.format(total))
```